# Graphing realizations of a random process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let's say we have a random process. Let's define this Random process to be $U(t)$ = $A$ where $A$ is uniform over $[-1,1]$.

What would a few sample realizations of this random process look like? I'm trying to understand random processes (I guess because of the interval this is also a Discrete Time Process) and I think some sample graphs would really help visualize it.

For example, I am not sure if it is a graph with a straight line at $y$ = $\frac{1}{2}$ or if it should bounce back and forth between $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$. Furthermore, would it be only positive values because we can't have negative probability?

Thanks!

---

**Edit** :

Some people have expressed that I have been unclear in my asking of the question. The question I found in the textbook I am learning from simply asks "Sketch a few sample realizations." Now looking at it, I guess that could mean one of two things: Either uniformly samples at each step as one graph below shows or uniformly sampled over the whole interval. Unfortunately, I don't exactly know what I want, but in this way I am learning. So please help me learn about random processes and how to approach them. If it helps, another part to the question is "What is a geometric interpretation of the auto correlation function?". Now to me that sounds like a graph - more specifically a vector. Is that along the lines of these "realizations" the question is talking about? Unfortunately I am giving you all the information the question contains and can't provide any more detail, but I am willing to learn!

Comment: The graph would be a straight horizontal line at the height $A$.

Comment: Is that the only realization? Could there be others? Additionally, if that is the case, what would the geometric interpretation of the auto correlation function be?

Comment: Do you mean: 1) $U(t) = A$ where we uniformly sample $A$ once from $[-1,1]$ or, 2) $U(t) = A_t$ where $A_t$ is sampled uniformly from $[-1,1]$ at each time-step?

Comment: "Could there be others?" In case this is worth mentioning, my comment is concerned with the situation described in the question, not with others, thus it deals with case 1) of @ErikM's comment, not with case 2). Note that the graph of case 2) would look like the filling of the whole strip Rx[-1,1]...

Comment: "I have been unclear in my asking of the question" Indeed you have but reading carefully what is written might help: $$U(t)=A$$ points unequivocally at case 1). Case 2) would correspond to $$U(t)=A_t$$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: So is that uniformly sampled at each time-step?

Comment: @Billy Thorton Yes. Uniform, independent at each step.

Comment: Ahh okay. That makes sense. Now bare with me as I try to understand this, but if this was done once over the whole interval, then we we would be looking at a straight line? Would there be any other possibilities besides a straight line? I mean the process being uniform at $[-1,1]$ we would at least that one straight line at $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Billy Thorton Think of it as rolling a die with an infinite number of faces, each of which shows a different number between -1 and 1. In this example the first roll yields $-.4$, the second $-.93$, ... the 50th is $-.89$. There is no straight line anywhere. The only straight line is in the density function of $U$, which is a horizontal line at height $1/2$ between -1 and 1, but that is a totally different graphic -- see e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformDistribution.html .